# Why is this quotient map surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a CW-complex and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism which sends each cell to a distinct cell and $f^2=id$.

Let $q:X\rightarrow X/x\sim f(x)$ be the quotient map and let $R$ be a ring with $1/2$. How do I prove that $q_*:H_i(X,R)\rightarrow H_i(X/x\sim f(x),R)$ is surjective for each $i$?

Since $f$ sends cells to cells and $f$ is a homeomorphism, $f$ is a cellular map. Hence $f_*:H_i(X^i,X^{i-1})\rightarrow H_i(X^i,X^{-1})$ is an isomorphism. How do I proceed next?